# How to make uppercase while doing <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have to make uppercase of all node values inside a parent node while copying the whole section.

For Example:
    ATPM/37        zATP - Miscellaneous Exceptions    Blank text  box without number    1       Said        
Change to:
    ATPM/37       ZATP - MISCELLANEOUS EXCEPTIONS    BLANK TEXT  BOX WITHOUT NUMBER    1      SAID

Comment: Do remember to format your code samples, so that others can read them easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, try adding

`<xsl:template match="text()">`
`<xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>`
`</xsl:template>`

In XSLT 1.0, use

```
<xsl:template match="text()"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $smallcase, $uppercase)" /> 
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" /> 
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

The `xsl:copy-of` instruction always does an exact copy; you can't use it to make a copy-with-changes. For that, use the identity template to copy things that you want to copy exactly, and a different template for things that you want to change. Thus:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```